# a:hover image overflow issue

Tags: html, css, hyperlink, hover

I'm creating a hover effect so that when someone mouse-over's on an image scan lines appear, but can't get the damn overlay image to be the same size as the image.

Take a look at this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/number8pie/wwmPL/

Here's the HTML:

```
<div class="container">
 <a href="#">
  <div class="overlay"></div>        
  <img src="http://www.mainlymunros.co.uk/images/green%20square.bmp" repeat>
 </a>
</div>
```

Here's the CSS:

```
.container {
  position: relative;
  max-width: 200px;
}
img {
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  padding: 7px;
  border: 1px solid #333;
}
.overlay {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 5;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 8px;
  background: url(https://dl.dropbox.com/u/29825082/scanlines.png) repeat;
}

a:hover .overlay {
  display: block;
}
```

If you hover over the green block you can see the scan lines overlap at the bottom, I want to remove this overlap.

The image is dynamic and changes size depending on the size of the browser size.

Anyone got any suggestions?

Comment: Are you looking for a CSS only solution?  I ask because this can be easily done with jQuery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're giving it 100% height and 100% width but then you're giving it margin. You're telling it to be the exact size of it's containing `a` element, but then pushing it down a bit.

You need to add an extra container, remove the image's padding and border and assign that to the new container.

```
<a href="#">
    <div class="image">
        <div class="overlay"></div>        
        <img src="http://www.mainlymunros.co.uk/images/green%20square.bmp"/>
    </div>
</a>

.container a { 
    display:block;
    padding:7px;
    border: 1px solid #333;
}
.image {
    position:relative;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    display:block;
}
img {
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
}
.overlay {
    display: none;
    position:absolute;
    z-index: 5;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: url(https://dl.dropbox.com/u/29825082/scanlines.png) repeat;
}
```

Example: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wwmPL/4/).

Your problem now is that your `img` **isn't square**. Being a rectangular image with greater width than height means it will fill 100% width but cut off part of the height. Make your image a square or give your overlay the same aspect ratio and this will work perfectly.

Comment: I see what your saying in regards to the margin but it didn't look like an overlap of 8px, it looked much more. I've used and saved your fiddle, and altered it a bit, it's almost there, just now the .image div is creating unwanted space in the bottom so the padding looks uneven. http://jsfiddle.net/number8pie/wwmPL/6/

Comment: Ah, fixed it! http://jsfiddle.net/wwmPL/7/ I've added `line-height:0;` to your `a` element. This removes that bottom bit. I've also set the height of the overlay back to 100%.

Comment: BRILLIANT! Why on earth line-height should affect a div I don't know, I was always under the impression line height is for formatting copy. Anyway, thanks James.

Answer (score 0):

its padding property which creates overflow. so change the height of both image and .overlay

that will do.

```
 fiddle :http://jsfiddle.net/wwmPL/2/
```

i hope this that solves your problem :)

Comment: He's already said that the image can vary in height. Using `height` isn't an option.

Comment: in that case javaScript is the only option.

Read Image size and assign the same to .overlay